# Limited count of column in XLSX file

Tags: r, excel

I should generate a big excel spreadsheet with `XLConnect`. I am filling each column in this spreadscheet with my calculation and at the end I am writing my calculation in the spreadscheet:

```
writeWorksheetToFile(file=FileName,mtr,startRow=1,startCol=strcol,sheet="Sheet1",header=FALSE,rownames=FALSE)
```

but if I a open the excel file I can only see until `AMJ` coloumn. Is there a way, that I see my total column or the count of columns in XLSX file is limited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure Kaja about this, because I use a convenience wrapper for XLConnect, but all I need to provide as arguments are the object I want to print to file (for you, "mtr") and the filename, such as perhaps "mtr.print.xlsx".

Why do you need to specify the startRow?  Also, perhaps your startCol argument only leaves the AMJ column?  Have you tried omitting it?

In short, only all the R object and the filename and see what happens.